# Disable sequelize column returning

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Good afternoon, everyone. I have a database with users' secret information. I want to disable returning of column "password" when I use findOne(). How can I do it without deleting it from the response object?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return all the fields except one, you can use the `exclude` attribute like this :

```js
    myTable.findOne({
        attributes: {exclude: ['password']},
        where: { id: userId }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do that while defining your schema by using [`toJson`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#instance-method-toJSON)
it allows you to edit your returned schema like this

```
sequelize.define('user', attributes, {
  instanceMethods: {
    toJSON: function () {
      const values = Object.assign({}, this.get());

      delete values.password;
      return values;
    }
  }
});
```